# Iterate Array of object in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I want to interate array object inside the ***subscribe***

**test.ts file**

```
  export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
      title = 'app works!';
      observableBooks: Observable<Book[]>
      books: Book[];
      newarray: any[];
      errorMessage: String;
      constructor(private bookService: BookService) { }
      ngOnInit(): void {
           this.observableBooks = this.bookService.getBooksWithObservable();
               this.observableBooks.subscribe(books => { 
             for (let entry of books) {
               // push the value into db
          }

         let retrivedata: Array<number> = //retrive the db collection again




                error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
              });

      }

    }
```

**test.html file**

```
<ul *ngFor="let book of retrivedata | async">
      <li>{{book.price}}</li>
    </ul>
```

I need to iterate this "arrayofObj" in HTML page, which means angular template page

Answer (score 3):

Try like this :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    private retrivedata: Array<any> = [];

    title = 'app works!';
    observableBooks: Observable<Book[]>
    books: Book[];
    newarray: any[];
    errorMessage: String;
    constructor(private bookService: BookService) { }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.observableBooks = this.bookService.getBooksWithObservable();
        this.observableBooks.subscribe(books => {
            console.log('books', books);
            this.retrivedata = books;
            for (let entry of this.retrivedata) {
                console.log('entry', entry)
            }
        }, (error) => {
            this.errorMessage = <any>error
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Would it not be better to type cast it at observable level as an array of items? For example... this.http.get<Book[]>(url).subscribe(books => {

      books.forEach((book, index) => {

          console.log("Book: " + JSON.stringify(book ) + " : at index: " + index);

      });

    }, error => console.log('Could not load book.'));

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare a class variable to hold the information you are getting inside subscription 'books'.

You cannot use `let retrivedata: Array<number> = //retrive the db collection again` on your view. You need to declare this variable in a class level.
Take a look:

```
 export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
  title = 'app works!';

  retrivedata: Array<object> = []; // your view variable has to be created in a class level

  observableBooks: Observable<Book[]>
  books: Book[];
  newarray: any[];
  errorMessage: String;

  constructor(private bookService: BookService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

       this.bookService.getBooksWithObservable().subscribe(books => { 
         books.forEach(entry => {
           this.retrievedata.push(entry);  //assign the data from subscription to your class variable
         }
      }

 }
```

then in your view:

```
<ul *ngFor="let book of retrivedata"> // use your class variable in your view
  <li>{{book.price}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you have to use `this` keyword to access them inside functions `this.my_class_variable_example`

Comment: you have to add the this keyword to your `forEach` as I have explained.

Comment: i didn't notice he had another class books, however, the books in the observables is not the same as the class. therefore no `this` added to that.

Answer (score 0):

Update :

I think if we make the code a bit cleaner, it should look close to this :

app.component.ts :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {    
    books: Book[];
    errorMessage: string;
    constructor(private bookService: BookService) { }

    loadBooks() {
        this.bookService.getBooksWithObservable().subscribe(
            (res) => this.onSuccess(res.json),
            (res) => this.onError(res.json)
        );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadBooks();
    }

    private onSuccess(data) {
        this.books = data;
    }
    private onError(error) {
        this.errorMessage = error.toString();
    }
}
```

HTML :

```
<div *ngFor="let book of books">
    <span>{{book.price}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't declare 'arrayofObj', I'm geting the following error  `Cannot find name 'arrayofObj'`

Comment: You need to declare arrayofObj as a class variable (like you did for books and errorMessage). It should be arrayofObj: any[]; and then you access it with this.arrayofObj inside ngOnInit

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what you have now in your ts file and in your html ?

Comment: are you using `forEach` to iterate over books and then access  `arrayofObj` ?

Comment: I don't understand your code, and some variables disappeared. What is retrivedata and newarray ? I am not sure if this is what you want to achieve, but you don't need to use a for loop inside your subscribe to get the books, you just assign it to a variable.

Comment: are you trying to give a value to `arrayofObj` inside the `subscribe` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate an array, but you are inside the `subscribe`, and if you are using forEach, you need then to add the `this` parameter for `forEach` to access the outside scope.

**Example:**

```
this.observableBooks.subscribe(
   (books) =>  {
                   this.books = books;

                   //iterate over arrayofObj
                   books.forEach( (book) => {
                                              //this will work 
                                              this.arrayofObj.push({fname: this.book.name});
                                  }, this);
                   });
```

Comment: yes, I tried, but getting  `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of null
    at AsyncPipe.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.AsyncPipe._dispose (common.es5.js:2761)`

Comment: I used that in my own project.

Comment: <div *ngFor="let obj of arrayofObj">
    <span>{{obj.fname}}</span>
    <span>{{obj.lname}}</span>
</div> shall I use array of obj like this in html

Comment: `for (let entry of books) {
          console.log(entry); // 1, "string", false
          try {
            users.insert({
              username: entry.name
             });
            } catch(error) {
          //  console.log(error);
            }
         
      }

      console.log(users.get(1));
      this.bookArr = db.getCollection('users').data || db.addCollection('users', {
        unique: ['username']
      }).data;`

Comment: please edit your code in the question. difficult to read in comment. you need to populate arrayofObj inside the subscribe depending on the values in  `this.books` in order then to use it in the UI template. confirm if this is the case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157757/discussion-between-hornet-and-hdjemai).

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.service.getDevicesByJson().subscribe(data => 
  {
    this.devicesJson = data;

    objArray = JSON.parse(this.devicesJson.toString());

    for(let obj of  objArray)
    {
      let info = new DeviceInfo();
      info.Address = obj["deviceAddress"]
      info.Name = obj["deviceName"]

      this.devices2.push(info)
    }

  });
```